# Error trying to move file

Tags: linux, mv

I was installing osclass on AWS and through the process of moving/renaming the file  called ' to the website I came across an error "

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-17-158 html]$ mv . mywebsite
mv: cannot move ‘.’ to ‘mywebsite’: Device or resource busy
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `mv` the current directory.

Instead, do this :

```
cd .. # parent dir
mv dirname /path/to/mywebsite
```

Comment: Note to the OP: `.`is shorthand for the current active directory

Comment: The correct terminology is "present working directory", hence the `pwd` command.

Comment: This should be changed in Linux. Flying on a directory to different locations ought to be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

For fast usage, you may use:

```
mv * mywebsite
```

This will cause an error saying it cannot move mywebsite inside mywebsite, but will move all other files, except hidden files.

If you're using bash you can fix it by enable the extglob via:

> shopt -s extglob

then you can use:

```
mv !(mywebsite) mywebsite
```

it will move all files except website to website folder.

If you want a more complicated and elegant solution (and also works with hidden files), you may use:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name mywebsite -exec mv {} mywebsite \;
```

A last solution can be a loop:

```
for file in $(ls -1 | grep -v mywebsite); do mv $file mywebsite; done
```

Comment: Never parse `ls` output.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain please?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: try `ls -b | cat` you will be surprised... just don't use `ls` if you don't know the correct parameters...